# R 4.0.4 upgrading R packages on Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: r, raspberry-pi

I installed **R 4.0.4** from source on **Raspberry Pi 400**, which uses ARM processessors.  This seemed fine.

However, when I tried to upgrade installed packages I ran into a few problems.

My question is:  After installing R 4.0.4 but **before upgrading packages**, what
steps should I take to insure the package upgrade will be successful?

This is what I did do; which did not succeed:

First, I ran packageStatus to see ~29 packages needed an upgrade.

```
x  <- packageStatus()
print(x)
```

Then a did the upgrade which reported ~ 31 warnings (packages that had non-zero exit status).  About 1 or 2 packages did upgrade successfully.

```
upgrade(x, ask=FALSE)
update(x)
```

However, I also noted errors during the upgrade such as:

- Wrong ELF class ELFCLASS64.
- lazy loading failed for package:   "DT"

Thanks.

Comment: Currently R-4.0.4 is still rather new. So several packages may have updated and cause dependencies to crash. Maybe this is the cause of your problem? It is not an uncommon strategy to wait a time to reduce the risk of package upgrade crashing automated setups.

Comment: Outside of this, you could use the `renv` package to create a static image of your packages and a new image for upgrading. That way you can always "regret" your upgrade at minimum cost by switching image.

Comment: What previous version were the packages installed using? In general packages are not compatible between major version changes. Packages would need to be reinstalled when doing from <4 to 4. Normally R creates library paths which include the major/minor version number so you can't easily use the incorrect versions. Just copying over old packages to the new version of R is generally a very bad idea.

Comment: I was upgrading from R-4.0.3 to R-4.0.4 but on RaspberryPi 400.   One upgrade solution is to study install.packages() error msgs carefully, using verbose=TRUE.   Then either adding missing Debian package or installing certain R package.   Then repeat.   Tedious but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process worked, tedious, but worked.

Upgrading packages from R-4.0.3 to R-4.0.4 on Raspberry Pi 400.

- study install.packages() error msgs carefully, using verbose=TRUE.
- Then either add missing Debian package or install certain R package.
- Then repeat. Tedious but works.

Comment: This old post was helpful too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149090/error-installing-minqa-in-r-3-0-2